# Monodevelop cannot connect to debugger

Tags: monodevelop

I have been using Ubuntu with MonoDevelop that I compiled myself. When I run a program it executes fine in gnome-terminal.

Now I am using Manjaro Linux and when I run program in MonoDevelop, I get an error stating that it cannot connect to the debugger. Apparently, it is to do with --disable-factory argument that was removed. However, the version of gnome-terminal is exactly the same as the Ubuntu version. Why does this happen?

Comment: if Ubuntu worked for you, you shouldn't switch to a different Linux; this is mainly the whole reason of why Linux is not ready to be mainstream on the desktop: fragmentation

Comment: This doesn't work with Ubuntu any more.